# Why the imaginary value in the plot differs from the equation?

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm reading control systems engineering 7th by nise. The author discusses a second-order system with two poles and no zeros. In the s-domain, the system is represented as

$$
\frac{b}{s^2 + as + b}
$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constant numbers and $s$ a complex variable. If we define $w_n = \sqrt{b}$ and $\zeta = \frac{a}{2 w_n}$ to be the natural frequency and the damping ratio, respectively, the the poles of the system in case underdamped system is

$$
s_{1,2} = - \zeta w_n \pm (w_n \sqrt{\zeta^2-1} ) 
$$

which is the equation numbered in the book as (4.24). So far so good. The plot of these poles in the complex plane is (i.e. Figure 4.11 in the book)

[image]

Why in the plot, the imaginary value differs from the equation while the real value is the same?

Comment: Looks like both are consistent with the equation to me.

Comment: @probably_someone, so $\sqrt{1- \zeta^2} = \sqrt{\zeta^2 -1}$?

Comment: No, they differ by a factor of $j$, but the imaginary axis is also multiplied by $j$, so they're consistent.

Comment: There shouldn't be a $j$ in the expression for $s_{1,2}$. Then $\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}=j\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}$

Comment: @user5713492, true. got it. I've removed $j$ from the equation. Thank you for both of you.